# Shrink input field in certain screen sizes with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap.

I try to make a navbar that contains a form and navigation.
I would like to shrink the input field in certain screen sizes.

Right now it looks like this.

This is OK:

[image]

In these cases I want to shrink the input field:

[image]
[image]

Relevant HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site Name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Subscribe</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">First Menu Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this CSS:

```
.navbar-form .form-control {
  width: 100px; // your width
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-form .form-control {
    width: 150px; // your width
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. However the submit button is still underneath the shrinked input field in the last case. How can I put it next to the input field, when there is enough space?

Comment: You should move your button HTML element to `form-group` div.

Comment: Right now, my code looks like this:

`<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Subscribe</button>
   </div>
          </form>`

But the submit button stil underneath.

Comment: Ah sorry, you have to add `display: inline-block` to your `form-control` in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Do these changes
In HTML:

```
<ul id="navbarRight" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

Instead of

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

above  is the last.
And add this CSS

```
        #navbar{
            width: 100%;
        }
        form{
            max-width: 45%;
        }
        #navbarRight{
            max-width: 55%;
        }
```